# Purecss Grids Offset Class

Tags: yui-pure-css

I have been evaluating purecss and would like to know whether in its grid system there is an equivalent to Bootstrap's offset class.

The grids doco does not mention such a thing.

Thanks

Comment: check out : https://gist.github.com/emirpprime/462fc0c230fcfad3bdd9

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, PureCSS doesn't have explicit support for Grid offsets; they seem to believe this is easy enough to tackle within the code of your own application.

See also:

- GitHub Issues on PureCSS's repo ([#318](https://github.com/yahoo/pure/issues/318),[#382](https://github.com/yahoo/pure/issues/382))
- The documentation on [adding padding and borders to grid units](http://purecss.io/grids/#applying-padding-and-borders-to-grid-units)
- [Snip2code example](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/120923/CSS-to-add-offsets-to-Pure-grids-http---) by emirpprime of purecss offset add-on
- [A discussion](https://alpha.app.net/danielgenser/post/21351700) started by Daniel Genser on app.net

You can, however, fake it:

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <p class="pure-u-1-3">This would be displayed in the middle third.</p>
</div>
```

This isn't as "pure" (pun intended) as an offset, but it works, so I've used it.

It might not hurt to chime in on one of the issue reports if you'd like offsets in purecss, although so far it sounds like something they've chosen not to include.

Comment: Looks like it to me, yes.